# Is there a way to force Pocket to add URL as Article?

Tags: pocket, ebook-reader

When I want to add some URL to Pocket - sometimes Pocket decides
to add it under "all items" instead of "articles".

Is there any way to force Pocket to add URL as Article ?

The reason I am asking for it is that I have a Kobo Aura HD ebook
reader and I can sync pocket articles ( only items marked as articles )
but not items under "all items"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to write to Pocket team to manually add such webpage.